# Get an array and display it php

Tags: php, html

We are bulding a simple module  in php, but we have a error that produces a bad encoding for html page :

```
<?php       
  $ids = array('363', '367', '366', '365','364','371','370','456','461');
?>

<div class="Staff">
    <?php foreach ($ids as $ids) {
      $user   = Foundry::user($ids);
     }?>
    <?php foreach ($ids as $user => $ids) { ?>
        <img alt="<?php echo $user->getName();?>"  src="<?php echo $user->getAvatar();?>" data-popbox="module://easysocial/profile/popbox" data-popbox-position="top-left" data-user-id="<?php echo $user ?>" />
        <a href="<?php echo $user->getPermalink();?>"><?php echo $user->getName();?></a>
    <?php}?>
</div>
```

Any Idea? , thanks as always for the help.

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: Your code has an error because of this line **<?php } ?>** copy and paste this.

Comment: $ids as $ids ? .. it's the same name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should like below:

```
<?php foreach ($ids as $id) { 
    $user   = Foundry::user($id);
?>
    <img alt="<?php echo $user->getName();?>"  src="<?php echo $user->getAvatar();?>" data-popbox="module://easysocial/profile/popbox" data-popbox-position="top-left" data-user-id="<?php echo $user ?>" />
    <a href="<?php echo $user->getPermalink();?>"><?php echo $user->getName();?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this:

```
<?php
$ids = array('363', '367', '366', '365','364','371','370','456','461');
?>

<div class="Staff">
    <?php foreach ($ids as $id) { ?>
        $user = Foundry::user($id);
        <img alt="<?php echo $user->getName();?>"  src="<?php echo $user->getAvatar();?>" data-popbox="module://easysocial/profile/popbox" data-popbox-position="top-left" data-user-id="<?php echo $user ?>" />
        <a href="<?php echo $user->getPermalink();?>"><?php echo $user->getName();?></a>
    <?php}?>
</div>
```